# Как изменить метабокс таксономий?

Tags: wordpress

Как добавить поиск в метабокс.
[image: print]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За вывод метабокса отвечает параметр `meta_box_cb` в `register_taxonomy`:

```
register_taxonomy( [ 
    ...
    'meta_box_cb' => 'my_callback_for_taxonomy_meta_box',
    ...
] );
```

Можете вывести в видете `select` с атрибутом `multiple`. И подключить `select2`. Тогда будет поиск и в целом неплохой вид метабокса